# What is the best way from universal app and converting storyboard in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, app-store

I'm working on an iOS app, that should work fine with both iphones and ipads.
As I know we can build the app as universal or convert iphone storyboard into ipad storyboard.What I want to know is, what is the best way from these and, when we launch app to app store, is it a problem to have two storyboards one for iphone and another for ipad.

Comment: Multiple storyboards should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is, what is the best way

That depends on your needs. Do you want the interface to be the same on iPhone and iPad, except sized differently? Then you may be able to use a single storyboard and rely on autolayout to adapt to different devices. If you want different interfaces on iPhone and iPad, perhaps to take better advantage of a much larger screen, then use different storyboards for each device type. You should still use autolayout in each storyboard, though, because within each device type there are several different screen sizes.

> is it a problem to have two storyboards one for iphone and another for iPad

No.

Answer (score 1):

Two storyboards for each type of device is a best way. As a result you will have more usable and careful UX for both types. But this way require a little bit more time for developing.